# Material-ui Tabs Left Alignment Issue

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

material-ui's current version does not support left-aligning tabs in the  component. I saw a workaround on
https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4420

Here's my implementation of the same
https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KpxVgwKOLPfM8CFcu5-

But when the first tab is selected the Tab Bar is distorted and has more height than desired.

Comment: It's due to the browser default margin-top of h2 tag but I'm astonished that why it happens only on the first tab and not on others

Comment: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kpxe2ZFusbklvY9ADmo

Comment: I want to have a container margin after the tabs end.

Comment: I updated the `webpack-bin` ^^

Comment: You should add those comments in the question (post)

Comment: This is now the default behavior, check the new version / beta

Answer (score 1):

## Left align

> An initial migration of the Tabs component has been merged on the next branch.
> That feature was implemented and is now the default behavior.
> Thanks for providing those details.

This is a supported [feature](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4420#issuecomment-317969072) in [v1-beta](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/v1-beta)

#### Fix Height issue

> The Tab Bar is distorted and has more height than desired.

```
headline: {{ marginTop: '0px' }}
```

See: [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319155/material-ui-tabs-left-alignment-issue/45333713#comment77600543_45319155)

#### Use padding

> I want to have a container margin after the tabs end.

The tabs structure is really weird to me, 
for some reason you can't use margin, try to use padding instead:

```
contentContainerStyle={{ paddingTop:'50px' }}
```

#### Set width

Don't set the width in `tabItemContainerStyle`, use a wrapper instead:

```
<div calssName='wrapper' style={{ width: '500px' }} /> 
    <Tabs {...}/>
</div>
```

[Example (webpackbin)](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kpxe2ZFusbklvY9ADmo)